# How to migrate your codebase from Python2 to Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm thinking to migrate my Python2.x codebase to python3.x. My anticipation is to do the following things:

1. Migrate Python2 syntax in Python3
2. Migrate all used packages and libraries which are compatible on Python3
3. Make sure all tests (unit tests) pass during and after the migration and fix iteratively.

What are your suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The project [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/2to3.html) is very helpful with this.

It can take care of the most common Python2->Python3 code changes that need to take place. You can run this on your tests also. From there I'd get a Python3 virtual environment, install pylint, and lint your codebase.

The migration process from 2 to 3 can be a bit cumbersome for large codebases. [This article](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) does a great job with in-depth explanations.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing all of the resources!